# Writing a procedure with an array as out parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I can't create a PL/SQL stored procedure. For example returns all of the ename of employees in deptno 20.

```
  create table emp(
  empno    number(4,0),
  ename    varchar2(10),
  job      varchar2(9),
  mgr      number(4,0),
  hiredate date,
  sal      number(7,2),
  comm     number(7,2),
  deptno   number(2,0),
  constraint pk_emp primary key (empno),
  constraint fk_deptno foreign key (deptno) references dept (deptno)
);
```

This is what i manage to do but i can't seem to move/write it into a procedure.

```
declare
      TYPE name_array IS TABLE OF emp.ename %type
       INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

      enames name_array;
    begin
      update emp set empno = empno where deptno = 20
      returning ename bulk collect into enames;
      for i in 1..enames.count loop
     dbms_output.put_line('ename : '||enames(i));
     end loop;

    end;
    /
```

Comment: Well what is the specific error?

Comment: i'm not sure on how to write them in a stored procedure. @OldProgrammer

Comment: By chance could you write an example of a stored procedure with in and out parameters ? @OldProgrammer

Comment: You should create standalone type, or define it in a package specification, as per Brian's answer. Why are you using associative array? You do not need it, you are using bulk collect - ordinary array (or nested table, as called by Oracle) should be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When returning a single object (which includes a table of values), I prefer functions over *out* parameters. Here is code that implements both.

```
drop table emp purge;
drop table dept purge;
CREATE TABLE dept
(
    deptno    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE emp
(
    empno NUMBER (4, 0)
  , ename VARCHAR2 (10)
  , job VARCHAR2 (9)
  , mgr NUMBER (4, 0)
  , hiredate DATE
  , sal NUMBER (7, 2)
  , comm NUMBER (7, 2)
  , deptno NUMBER (2, 0)
  , CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY (empno)
  , CONSTRAINT fk_deptno FOREIGN KEY (deptno) REFERENCES dept (deptno)
);

CREATE or replace PACKAGE emp_pkg
AS
    TYPE name_array_t IS TABLE OF emp.ename%TYPE
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    FUNCTION upd (p_empno IN emp.empno%TYPE)
        RETURN name_array_t;

    PROCEDURE upd (
        p_empno   IN     emp.empno%TYPE
      , p_names      OUT name_array_t
    );
END emp_pkg;

CREATE or replace PACKAGE BODY emp_pkg
AS
    FUNCTION upd (p_empno IN emp.empno%TYPE)
        RETURN name_array_t
    AS
        l_names   name_array_t;
    BEGIN
           UPDATE emp
              SET empno   = empno
            WHERE deptno = 20
        RETURNING ename
             BULK COLLECT INTO l_names;

        RETURN l_names;
    END upd;

    PROCEDURE upd (
        p_empno   IN     emp.empno%TYPE
      , p_names      OUT name_array_t
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        p_names   := upd (p_empno);
    END upd;
END emp_pkg;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample Stored Proc with return type as Array
create

```
procedure sample_proc(p_cust_id in number, p_customers out custarray)
as
my_cust custarray := custarray();
```